# setMyLocationButtonEnabled instance member not found in ionic-native Google Maps

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, google-maps-sdk-ios, ionic-native

I'm having an issue with the instance member of Google Maps native plugin for Ionic framework (latest version - 2.0).

The instance member is [setMyLocationButtonEnabled(enabled)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/#setMyLocationButtonEnabled).

The map has been displayed correctly, as I've configured it with API keys and added the plugin module to `NgModule` in the `app.module.ts` file.

Yet I'm not 100% sure I added the plugin correctly, I've done it this way:

`import { GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps'
(...)
@NgModule({...
  providers:[
    GoogleMaps,
(...)`

And also, I've checked the `npm list` and it shows the following regarding the google maps packages:

[image: npm list googlemaps packages]

I've tried installing this package, but when I copy the link with the last bit "#2.6.0" it says it can't find the package. It works without that, and I installed it but it didn't change anything.

Anyone knows what should I do?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: Found that this method is not yet implemented (or launched), when opening this [issue](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2122).

Also, it has been updated by one side (ionic-native team) as seen in this PR: [#2320](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/2320), but I think npm package has not been updated yet.